# How to add if statement for the request doesn't contain header then reject

Tags: api, go, handler

This is my API Handler for handling the request, I am trying to add if statement which checks that if it contain header with a token if not then reject, basically I have to read header here.

```
func getLeads(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //if the request doesn't contain header then reject
     if r.Header.Get("Content-Type") = nil {
        fmt.Println("Request Rejected")
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var leads []Lead
    db, err := getDB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    db.Find(&leads)
    // todo: error handling
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(leads)
}
```

Comment: This statement is not working

Comment: Syntax is not right I think.

Comment: syntax error: assignment r.Header.Get("Content-Type") = nil used as value

Comment: invalid operation: r.Header.Get("Content-Type") == nil (mismatched types string and nil)

Answer (score 0):

`Header.Get` cannot return `nil`. [Per the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get):

> Get gets the first value associated with the given key. If there are no values associated with the key, Get returns "".

You should be checking against `""`, not `nil`.